# database consistency in uwsgi+flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, uwsgi

I've got a problem about database consistency when using uwsgi+flask. Thank you for help!

Here is the table in the database:

```
id token school degree department enrollment
```

First, I update the school of which the token equals to e2477cdffa2ab00b178dc17a805a75a0.
Then, I select the school using the same token above.
I am using SQLAlchemy to access database in flask.

If the value of threads in uwsgi.ini is configured to 2:
After the update, the first (third, fifth...) select returns the old school value, but the second (fourth, sixth, eighth...) select returns the new value.

If the value of threads in uwsgi.ini is configured to 1, after update, all selects returns the new value.

Here are my uwsgi.ini and relative code:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
chdir = /home/www/app
wsgi-file = main.py
callable = app
processes = 1
threads = 3
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
buffer-size = 32768
uid = root
gid = root
logto = /home/www/logs/uwsgi.log
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid

def editschooldb(token,school,degree,department,enrollment):
    u = User.query.filter_by(token=token).first()

    if u!= None:
        u.school = school
        u.degree = degree
        u.department = department
        u.enrollment = enrollment
        try:
            db.session.add(u)
            db.session.commit()
            return 0
        except Exception, e:
            db.session.rollback()
            return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

Here are the results of tcpdump (threads = 2), from which we can see that at 09:43:06 flask process hits mysqlserver and select returns "school":"", but at 09:43:28 there is another select, which returns "school":"test123".

```
root@iZ25ko0w5hcZ:/home/www# tcpdump -i lo port 3306
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
09:43:06.187465 IP this.is.my.ip.45686 > this.is.my.ip.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 2937500406:2937501074, ack 1677732916, win 3637, options [nop,nop,TS val 119353277 ecr 119313822], length 668
09:43:06.187809 IP this.is.my.ip.mysql > this.is.my.ip.45686: Flags [P.], seq 1:1308, ack 668, win 425, options [nop,nop,TS val 119353277 ecr 119353277], length 1307
09:43:06.187823 IP this.is.my.ip.45686 > this.is.my.ip.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1308, win 3637, options [nop,nop,TS val 119353277 ecr 119353277], length 0
09:43:28.429654 IP this.is.my.ip.45689 > this.is.my.ip.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 1240221793:1240222461, ack 75923549, win 3637, options [nop,nop,TS val 119358838 ecr 119350800], length 668
09:43:28.429747 IP this.is.my.ip.mysql > this.is.my.ip.45689: Flags [P.], seq 1:1315, ack 668, win 436, options [nop,nop,TS val 119358838 ecr 119358838], length 1314
09:43:28.429759 IP this.is.my.ip.45689 > this.is.my.ip.mysql: Flags [.], ack 1315, win 3637, options [nop,nop,TS val 119358838 ecr 119358838], length 0

root@iZ25ko0w5hcZ:~# curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"token":"e2477cdffa2ab00b178dc17a805a75a0"}' "http://this.is.my.ip:8080/getprofile"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 01:43:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 317
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "birthday": "", 
  "degree": "", 
  "department": "", 
  "enrollment": "", 
  "gender": "\u5973", 
  "hobby": "", 
  "id": 2, 
  "name": "", 
  "phone": "", 
  "preference": "", 
  "reason": "", 
  "school": "", 
  "state": "successful", 
  "token": "e2477cdffa2ab00b178dc17a805a75a0", 
  "username": "just2012"
}
root@iZ25ko0w5hcZ:~# curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"token":"e2477cdffa2ab00b178dc17a805a75a0"}' "http://this.is.my.ip:8080/getprofile"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 01:43:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 324
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "birthday": "", 
  "degree": "", 
  "department": "", 
  "enrollment": "", 
  "gender": "\u5973", 
  "hobby": "", 
  "id": 2, 
  "name": "", 
  "phone": "", 
  "preference": "", 
  "reason": "", 
  "school": "test123", 
  "state": "successful", 
  "token": "e2477cdffa2ab00b178dc17a805a75a0", 
  "username": "just2012"
}
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with queryset caching. You could check if all `User.query` statements actuaklly hit the MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I've updated the post, in which logs were added. The logs shows that User,query really hit the MySQL server.

Comment: This happend to me once, and never found any kind of solution. Hope someone can throw some light.